# Tables to be numbered using Arabic numerals

Tags: tables

I need all tables to be numbered using Arabic numerals. The arabic numeration should be in table caption such as: `TABLE I, TABLE II` etc. and when I use the  `\ref{table:1}`. I added `\renewcommand{\thetable}{\arabic{table}}` and no change.
Here is my table:

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{booktabs,makecell,tabularx}
    \renewcommand\theadfont{\small}
    \newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
    \usepackage{siunitx}
    \renewcommand{\thetable}{\arabic{table}}

\begin{document}
\section{Results}
This is my Table \ref{table:1}:
    \begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{5pt}
    \small
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{c L S[table-format=6.0]*{2}{S[table-format=2.0]}}
    \toprule
\thead{ID}  &   \thead{UCI Dataset Name} 
                &   {\thead{Samples\\(numbers)}}
                    &   {\thead{Attributes\\(numbers)}} 
                        &   {\thead{Classes\\number}}           \\
    \midrule
DS1 & Cardiotocography                      & 2126  & 23    & 3     \\
DS2 & Wall-Following Robot Navigation Data  & 5456  & 24    & 4     \\
DS3 & Spambase                              & 4601  & 57    & 2     \\
DS4 & MAGIC Gamma Telescope                 & 19020 & 11    & 2     \\
DS5 & Letter Recognition                    & 20000 & 16    & 26    \\
DS6 & MiniBooNE particle identification     & 130065& 50    & 2     \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
    \caption{Datasets used for empirical evaluation}
    \label{table:1}
    \end{table}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: I think you're getting confused between roman and arabic numerals. What you want is ` \renewcommand{\thetable}{\roman{table}}` for i,ii etc or ` \renewcommand{\thetable}{\Roman{table}}` for I,II etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot. There was written "All tables are to be numbered using Arabic numerals". Am  I right? with \renewcommand{\thetable}{\arabic{table}} or to leave it with Latex default?

Comment: Arabic (1,2,3,...) is the default, but you say you want I, II, III, ... (which would be Roman).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `arabic` is the the default for tables. If there is a need for TABLE I, TABLE II the change should be in `\renewcommand{\thetable}{\Roman{table}}`

Comment: Some classes set roman by default, so it can be useful to do `\renewcommand{\thetable}{\arabic{table}}` in some situations.